# Check variables existence in Typescript

Tags: typescript, tslint

I am updating an older `.ts` file, using TSlint (v3.15.1) and an updated version of typescript (2.0.3). I am getting some errors that I'd liketo solve.

The code is a simple existence test for some class properties:

```
export class myClass {
    private pUserName: string;
    private pUserPass: string;
    private pHost: string;
    private pPort: number;

constructor($host: string, $port: number) {
    this.pHost = $host;
    this.pPort = $port;
}   

public isReady(): boolean {
        return Boolean(this.pUserName && this.pUserPass && this.pJiraHost && this.pJiraPort);
}
```

Either I am getting a "[ts] cannot find name Boolean", or some "cannot convert string to boolean" ...

I am very new to typescript, could you help me on the correct way to write this ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround, which does not report any error. However, this is verbose and not very elegant... Any better idea ? :)

```
public isReady(): boolean {
    for (const property in ['pUserName', 'pUserPass', 'pHost', 'pPort']) {
        if (typeof(property) !== 'string') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you can go with `return !!(this.pUserName && this.pUserPass && this.pJiraHost && this.pJiraPort);` Beware - empty strings and zeros will be also reported as `false`

Answer (score 0):

I also found out that the es6 definition typings was not included :

now my tsconfig.json looks like :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES6",
        "outDir": "out",
        "noLib": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "removeComments": true
    },
    "include" : [
        "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts",
        "node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
        "node_modules/@types/q/index.d.ts",
        "node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts",
        "node_modules/@types/moment/index.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```